# "Add to Cart" button/from in template (form ID from Node ID)?

Tags: commerce

I'm working on a website made with D7 and the Commerce Module, with a "Products" view (for the Product content type) having this relationship field:

*(Products referenced by field_info_prodotto) Commerce Product: Add to Cart form*

I want this "Buy Now" button/form to also be inside each products' page (= in the template for the Product content type).

I can create a template for single nodes (see code), but how should I edit the general template (node--product-display.tpl.php)?

```
# node--181.tpl.php    
<form class="commerce-add-to-cart commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-24" autocomplete="off"
action="/en/products" method="post" id="commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-24" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div><input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="24">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_24">
<input name='form_token' type='hidden' value='<?php print drupal_get_token('commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_24'); ?>'>
<div id="edit-line-item-fields--9" class="form-wrapper"></div><input type="hidden" name="quantity"
value="1">
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit--9" name="op" value="Add to cart" class="form-submit">
</div>
</form>
```

(In the template there is already the code to show a "Buy Now" field - field_tab_5 - but that's just an empty text field and I suppose it's not what I'm after).

Comment: So, do you need only Add to cart form template?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I edited the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Can you please share the .tpl file name where you added your form?

Comment: I have added a form for a single node (node--181.tpl.php) and I could do the same for all the other nodes, but I'm looking for the way to edit only node--product-display.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

- Add a field of type "Product reference" to the Product content type ("Inline entity form - Multiple values" as widget)
- Use "Add to Cart Form" to its display format
- Field API in node--product-display.tpl.php:

  print render($content['field_info_prodotto']);